# Multiplication of a matrix by a transpose vector

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

I'm implementing the inverse power method to find the maximum eigenvalue of a matrix.Given a matrix $A$ ( n by n matrix ) and a vector $x$ a np.array with `shape: (len(A),)`: One of the steps of the implementation involves computing this value:

$q = x^TAx$

The thing is, i don't know if i'm implementing this the rigt way:

```
q = x.transpose() @ A @ x
```

Is there a better way to compute this?

Comment: The `transpose` of an array with shape (n,) has shape (n,) - it's the same thing!  But `@` works fine with a 1d array - see the docs.   So `x@A@x` returns a scalar value.  Is that what you want?  `np.dot(x, np.dot(A.x))` also works.  And `np.einsum('i,ij,j', x,A,x)`

Answer (score 1):

```
x = x.reshape(-1, 1) # or x = x.reshape(1, -1) if x is a row vector. 
A_times_x = np.matmul(A, x)
q = np.matmul(x.T, A)
```

instead of `np.matmul`, you should be able to use `np.dot` as well, but the former is more readable in my opinion.